# Background of List Item displaces when items are reordered

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I noticed this issue with flutter `ListView` and I am not sure how to go about resolving it.

I have a list of "questions" being rendered with a `ListView`, each question is rendered with a `ListTile` with a white background (tile color).

There is a feature to select a number of questions and then place them after a specific question, which basically help users position specific question(s) after a particular question. So when a question is selected, I enable/show a button below all other questions except the selected. This makes it possible for users to insert the selected questions at a particular position.

Now the problem is, when the questions are inserted, I see the background of one or more tile displace (not sure if that is the correct word) from the content, and you see the question without a background in the correct position and the background stuck at the original position.

I have attached 3 images to help understand what I am talking about.

Image showing list of questions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Cvj.png

Image showing the 2nd question selected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoSuu.png

Image showing second question placed after the original 3rd question(which is now 2nd) with displaced background: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZjXF.png

**This is the code snippet that renders the Questions.**

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: controller.mergedQuestions.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                var question = controller.mergedQuestions[i];
                return Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                   const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                    ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          question.question!,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          if(controller.multiSelectMode){
                            question.selected= !question.selected!;
                            controller.mergedQuestions.refresh();
                          }else{
                            controller.showQuestionEditor(question);
                          }
                        },
                        onLongPress: (){
                          question.selected = !question.selected!;
                          controller.mergedQuestions.refresh();
                        },
                        tileColor: Colors.white,
                        subtitle: Text(
                          "ANS: ${question.answer}",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                        trailing: question.selected!?const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.check_circle,
                            size: 30,
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                        ):const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.drag_handle,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                        ),
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.question_mark)),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: controller.multiSelectMode && !question.selected!,
                      child: Center(
                        child: TextButton(onPressed: (){
                          controller.insertQuestionsAfter(question);
                        }, child: Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                          ),
                          child: const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0,vertical: 5),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Text("Insert Here",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                Icon(Icons.add_circle,color: Colors.green,)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              })
```

Comment: Please include some code to understand how your ListView and tiles are implemented

Comment: @pcba-dev I have included the code, Thanks.

Comment: You should provide a Key to the widgets built by the "itemBuilder" of the ListView that uniquely identifies them and allows Flutter to identify them when rebuilding. However, I don't see how what you are showing in your screenshots is event possible... Are you running the app in debug?

Comment: Thank you very much.
Yes, I am running in debug mode.
I will try what you suggested and update you.
Thanks.

Comment: @pcba-dev Bro, It works!!, Thank you very much!!. That was the problem. Can you add it as an answer?

Comment: @pcba-dev I added a key to the parent column using the question as value(Each question is unique).

Comment: Glad it helped! I have added the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flutter, when using a `ListView` and encountering issues with item display during reordering, **ensure each item** in the list has **a key that uniquely identifies** them.

[Keys](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html) are used to uniquely identify and track widgets, enabling Flutter's reconciliation process to efficiently update the user interface. *Keys must be unique amongst the Elements with the same parent*. Keys distinguish widgets from each other, allowing Flutter to determine whether a widget needs to be updated, inserted, or removed. By providing keys, Flutter can accurately identify each item, preventing unexpected behavior when the list is reordered.

You could have a unique-Id in your `Question` objects which is generated on creation, and use that with `ValueKey(question.uid)`.